# awk para calcular edad media

Tags: awk

Tengo el siguiente dataset

```
PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,,S
2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",female,38,1,0,PC 17599,71.2833,C85,C
3,1,3,"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina",female,26,0,0,STON/O2. 3101282,7.925,,S
4,1,1,"Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)",female,35,1,0,113803,53.1,C123,S
5,0,3,"Allen, Mr. William Henry",male,35,0,0,373450,8.05,,S
6,0,3,"Moran, Mr. James",male,,0,0,330877,8.4583,,Q
7,0,1,"McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J",male,54,0,0,17463,51.8625,E46,S
```

En algunos casos - PassengerId 6 por ejemplo- el campo Age está vacío.

Para ello, quiero primero calcular la edad media de las celdas no vacías.

El `awk` que he comenzado a plantear es el siguiente:

```
BEGIN {FS=","}
$6~/ length($6) != 0/ {count++;tot+=$6}
END {avg=("%.2f/n", tot/count)}
```

,siendo `length($5) != 0` la condición <celda no vacía> que no soy capaz de indicar

Este valor lo quiero guardar en una variable para posteriormente asignarlo a las celdas vacías.

Quería saber si esta forma es adecuada. Quiero hacerlo con `awk` en todo caso y creo que guardando la variable es la mejor opción para luego asignarla mediante un bucle `for` o `while`, que es como debo hacerlo también.

Gracias.

Comment: No sería $6? Si numeramos en el caso que comentas veo `6[1], 0[2], 3[3], "Moran, Mr. James"[4], male[5], [6], ...`, porque awk no empieza en 0

Comment: @PabloLozano, tienes razón, lo corrijo sobre la consulta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ver si un campo no está, simplemente di `!$campo`.

En general, para calcular la media de los valores existentes puedes decir algo así como:

```
awk -F, '$7{sum+=$7; elementos++} END{print sum/elementos}' fichero
```

Comment: y si el valor lo quiero guardar en una variable, no puedo hacer ```var=awk -F, '$7{sum+=$7; elementos++} END{print sum/elementos}' fichero```?

Comment: Harías: `var=$(comando)`. En este caso, `var=$(awk -F, '$7{sum+=$7; elementos++} END{print sum/elementos}' fichero)`.